# Sard's theorem and Cantor set

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, morse-theory

Sard's famous theorem asserts that

**Theorem.** The set of critical values of a smooth function from a manifold to another has Lebesgue measure $0$.

I am asking for the curiosity that is it possible to find such a function whose set of critical values is

1. Cantor set or
2. Any other uncountably infinite set?

Comment: You might have looked at the first version of Sard's Theorem, which is more heavily cited.  He published a follow-up paper where he gave an upper bound on the Hausdorff dimension.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not hard to construct a smooth function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $f \ge 0$ with $f(x) = 0$ if and only if $x$ is in the Cantor set $E$.  If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, the critical values of $F$ will be an uncountably infinite perfect set.

Answer (score 5):

By a theorem of Whitney (easy in this $1$-dimensional case), any compact subset $K$ in the interval $I$ is the set of zeroes of a
smooth ($C^\infty$) nonnegative function $f$.
 As Robert said, take a primitive $F$. Provided that $K$ has no interior point, the critical values $F(K)$ of $F$ are homeomorphic with $K$.

Answer (score 1):

The paper "Hausdoff Measures and the Morse-Sard Theorem" by Moreira gives in section 4 a general construction of near-counterexamples involving generalized Cantor sets.

**Reference**

Carlos Gustavo T. de A. Moreira, "[Hausdorff measures and the Morse-Sard theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43736715)" (English), Publicacions Matemàtiques 45, No. 1, 149-162 (2001), [MR1829581](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1829581), [Zbl 0995.58007](https://zbmath.org/0995.58007).